# How to swap in transport in java gRPC as alluded to in docs?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

In reading java gRPC, the last paragraph makes a statement about changing the transport

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/README.md

I can't seem to find any documents on this.  I did dig through the gradle gRPC plugin which executes protoc with a protoc-gen-grpc-java plugin next.  After that, I can't seem to find the link into grpc-java project where the java plugin is invoked.  I am trying to track down the plugin point to see where okhttp or netty is swapped in but it's eluding me.

Anyone have any pointers on my needle in a haystack qwest?  (feels like looking like a needle so far).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated code, stub layer, doesn't interact with transport layer and vice versa. instead, you need to use channel layer to make them interact together. Each channel implementations in gRPC is transport specific such as NettyChannel, OkHttpChannel and InProcessChannel (or server for server side).

```
// GreeterGrpc is generated code to create a stub
YourServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

where channel can use one of those 3 provided transports; Netty, OkHttp, InProcess.

```
ManagedChannel channel =
  NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget(target).build();
//or,  OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget(target).build();
//or,  InProcessChannelBuilder.forTarget(target).build();
```

gRPC also provides service loader to provide preferred transport via
[ManagedChannelProvider](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/ManagedChannelProvider.java). you can use `ManagedChannelBuilder` to use environmental specific transport.